# Bash variable quoting in a function

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, parameter

I've defined a short helper function in a bash script.  For legibility, I'd like to replace the boilerplate headers with a variable declared outside the function.

I've tried quoting the declaration many different ways, but nothing's working.

I want to replace this

```
put() {
  local response=$(curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;' ...)
  echo $response
}
```

with something like this

```
headers=???

put() {
  local response=$(curl $headers ...)
  echo $response
}
```

i.e. `$headers` should expand to `-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'`

`$headers` needs to expand to separate words to get passed properly as arguments, so I've even tried using an array.

Note: I've pretty much given up.  It's not worth fighting with for such a simple use.  At this point the question is for edification.

Comment: `headers=(. ..)`. `curl "${headers[@]}"`

Comment: @icarus edited to clarify.  I'm not trying to pass in parameters.  I'm trying to have a variable in from outside the function.

Comment: @iruvar darn, I thought I tried that.  That was easy.

Answer (score 2):

This may be solved using an array:

```
headers=( -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;' )
```

You may then use `"${headers[@]}"` in your call to `curl`:

```
curl "${headers[@]}" URL
```

The quoting of the expansion ensures that the four entries in the array (`-H`, `Content-Type: application/json`, `-H`, and `Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;`) are individually quoted and therefore not further split by the shell.

Your function:

```bash
put () {
    curl "${headers[@]}" URL
}
```

Note that the `response` variable in your won implementation is unnecessary. Using it unquoted in the call to `echo` would additionally split its value on whitespace (by default) and apply filename globbing on each part.  Instead of using `echo` to output the result of the `curl` call, we can leave that to `curl`.